# Scriptwriting, screenplay writing, playwriting, blogging

Tags: creative-writing

Does a script usually have to come out like a play? Or, there should be a difference?

Comment: Hi Rolistance, welcome to writing.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information. Can you please expand on your question, what do you mean by "come out like a play"? I'm not sure exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

A "script" is general; a "screenplay" is something to be filmed. A "play" is something to be performed on a stage, and more limited because of that; for example all kinds of things can be done in a screenplay, with special effects, sound effects, dubbing, green screens, etc, things you just can't do on stage. For example, a person can literally dissolve or explode, or have their head blown off.

So while the screenplay and a stage play are very similar, and the acting is similar, they have slightly different conventions for what is included. Read [Screenplay, Stage play, Teleplay - What's the difference?](https://www.finaldraft.com/learn/screenplay-stageplay-teleplay-whats-difference/) as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

There are technical differences between a play and a screenplay. Amadeus has set you on a good path.

The, often overlooked, important difference between a play and screenplay is the required location discipline. A director may move cameras at any point to any location but there is only ONE stage.

Subsequently, if you were writing a play: "Emigrating to the New World."

ACT ONE: In the current family home.

ACT TWO: Aboard the ship for the long journey.

ACT THREE: In their shiny new home.

The above play would require TWO scene changes. You cannot switch back and forth between locations.

Comment: Wow! Makes real sense. Thank you for this insight, sir! I'll surely be sharing this with my friends.